Flutter Auto Complete with debouncer does not show values
I have a flutter code to create a custom autocomplete form field using debouncer.
I have put a debouncer of 800ms, and it hits the API which returns with correct data also. But the problem is that drop down fields do not appear.
Example: If the API returns set of countries based on the typed in text, and if I type in "Mada", the API returns "Madagascar", but the drop down does not show it.
The code is like so:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:abc/services/api_service.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class CustomAutoCompleteField extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> config;
  final String? initialValue;
  final FormFieldSetter<String> onSaved;
  final ApiService apiClient;

  CustomAutoCompleteField({
    Key? key,
    required this.config,
    this.initialValue,
    required this.onSaved,
    required this.apiClient,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomAutoCompleteFieldState createState() => _CustomAutoCompleteFieldState();
}

class _CustomAutoCompleteFieldState extends State<CustomAutoCompleteField> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  List<String> _options = [];
  bool _isLoading = false;
  Timer? _debounce;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = widget.initialValue ?? '';
    if (widget.config['options'] is List) {
      _options = List<String>.from(widget.config['options']);
    }
    _focusNode.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  void _onFocusChange() {
    setState(() {});  // Rebuild to update the floating label
  }

  Future<void> _getOptions(String pattern) async {
    if (pattern.isEmpty) {
      setState(() => _options = []);
      return;
    }

    if (widget.config['options'] is List) {
      // Static options
      setState(() {
        _options = _options.where((option) => 
          option.toLowerCase().contains(pattern.toLowerCase())).toList();
      });
    } else if (widget.config['api'] != null) {
      // API-based options
      setState(() => _isLoading = true);
      try {
        final apiConfig = Map<String, dynamic>.from(widget.config['api']);
        apiConfig['urlParams'] = {'search': pattern, 'page': '1'};
        
        final response = await widget.apiClient.makeApiCall(apiConfig);
        
        final List<dynamic> data = response['data'];
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
          _options = data.map((item) => item[widget.config['api']['labelKey']].toString()).toList();
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error fetching autocomplete options: $e');
        setState(() => _isLoading = false);
      }
    }
  }

  void _onChanged(String value) {
    if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce!.cancel();
    _debounce = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
      _getOptions(value);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: FormField<String>(
        initialValue: widget.initialValue,
        onSaved: widget.onSaved,
        validator: _validateAutoComplete,
        builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Autocomplete<String>(
                optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                  if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                    return const Iterable<String>.empty();
                  }
                  return _options.where((option) =>
                    option.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase()));
                },
                onSelected: (String selection) {
                  _controller.text = selection;
                  state.didChange(selection);
                },
                fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context, TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController,
                    FocusNode fieldFocusNode, VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
                  return TextFormField(
                    controller: fieldTextEditingController,
                    focusNode: fieldFocusNode,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: widget.config['label'] + (widget.config['required'] == true ? ' *' : ''),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                      suffixIcon: _isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : null,
                    ),
                    onChanged: _onChanged,
                  );
                },
              ),
              if (state.hasError)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, top: 8),
                  child: Text(
                    state.errorText!,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String? _validateAutoComplete(String? value) {
    if (widget.config['required'] == true && (value == null || value.isEmpty)) {
      return '${widget.config['label']} is required';
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
    _debounce?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


Where am I going wrong?

Can you provide sample API response?

{Key? key, required AutocompleteOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, AutocompleteOptionToString displayStringForOption = RawAutocomplete.defaultStringForOption, AutocompleteFieldViewBuilder fieldViewBuilder = _defaultFieldViewBuilder, AutocompleteOnSelected? onSelected, double optionsMaxHeight = 200.0, AutocompleteOptionsViewBuilder? optionsViewBuilder, OptionsViewOpenDirection optionsViewOpenDirection = OptionsViewOpenDirection.down, TextEditingValue? initialValue})
Creates an instance of Autocomplete.

hey please explain - if possible please suggest entire code.
